# How to bind sales header model to collection of sales Footer on SalesOrder controller using ASP.NET core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Problem

How to bind sales header Model to collection of sales Footer on SalesOrder controller using asp.net core 2.1 ?

I work on project have Sales Order form this form contain to :

salesHeader model

salesFooter model

so that i already have model Sales Header have navigation property to Sales 
Footer
as following

```
SalesHeader Model

public int SalesOrderNo { get; set; }
  public int SalesYear { get; set; }
  public ICollection<SalesFooter> SalesFooters { get; set; }


SalesFooter Model
public int SalesOrderNo { get; set; }
public int Quantity { get; set; }
public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
```

How to get collection of sales footer on :

on Edit action of sales Order controller how to get collection of sales footer ?

on Edit view(get) sales Order controller how to get collection of sales footer ?

What I have tried:

Repository

```
public T GetById(int Id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(Id);
        }
public class SalesOrderController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IrepositoryTab<SalesHeader> _repositoryHeader;
        public  SalesOrderController(IrepositoryTab<SalesHeader> SalesHeader, IrepositoryTab<SalesFooter> SalesFooter)
        {
            this._repositoryHeader = SalesHeader;
            this._repositoryFooter = SalesFooter;

        }

//get
//Edit Action of sales Order Controller 

public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
       {

           var SalesHeader = _repositoryHeader.GetById(id);
          //How to bind with sales footer
           return View();

       }

on Edit view of Sales Order Controller

 <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SalesOrderNo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SalesOrderNo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SalesOrderNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SalesYear" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SalesYear" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SalesYear" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
//How to bind Sales Header with Sales Footer

on view of sales Header
```

Comment: actually what i need is how to bind sales footer on view and controller only

Comment: can any one help me